# Does MariaDB-Galera cluster have error tolerance function on sst_user credential?

Tags: clustering, galera, mariadb-10.5

We have done the testing and confirmed the following system behavior of MariaDB-Galera clustering:

- The first-time bootstrap always needs to get everything correct, including the `sst_user` credentials in `wsrep_sst_auth`, and if choose to use SSL, `socket.ssl` related properties in `wsrep_provider_options`.
- After the first successful clustering joining, we can re-bootstrap the existing nodes **even with a wrong password for the `sst_user`**, and still get a successful joining.
  We guess the MariaDB-Galera software has a design for error tolerance. Confirm?
- The error tolerance above does not include the SSL certificates.
  So, when using SSL, if re-bootstrap with wrong certificates, e.g., the self-signing CA and Server certificates have the same Common Name. In this case, the Donor can still start but the Joiner will fail to join in, with log events of `WSREP: Handshake failed: tlsv1 alert unknown ca`.

**Our Questions:**

- Could we confirm whether there exists an "error tolerance" function on `sst_user` credential after the first-time successful joining?
- If yes, what is the mechanism?
- Do we have a reference or link to the documentation?

We highly appreciate any hints and suggestions.

**Details:**

See the below screenshot for the versions in the system under test.

```
# yum list installed | grep -i -e "maria" -e "galera" -e "garb"
MariaDB-backup.x86_64            10.5.23-1.el7.centos        @mariadb
MariaDB-client.x86_64            10.5.23-1.el7.centos        @mariadb
MariaDB-common.x86_64            10.5.23-1.el7.centos        @mariadb
MariaDB-compat.x86_64            10.5.23-1.el7.centos        @mariadb
MariaDB-server.x86_64            10.5.23-1.el7.centos        @mariadb
MariaDB-shared.x86_64            10.5.23-1.el7.centos        @mariadb
galera-4.x86_64                  26.4.16-1.el7.centos        @mariadb
```